# Getting sub strings using other columns in table - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, methods, substring

Trying to create a table to generate random data using 'faker', for my username column I wanted to concatenate two sub-strings from two other fields in my table.

For example:

```
First Name: John, Last Name: Abbott, Username: jabbott
```

I seed my data like so

```
  Post.create!(
      Lastname: Faker::Name.last_name,
      Firstname: Faker::Name.first_name,
      Username: " first letter of first name" + "lastname"
    )
```

Is there a sub string method that does this on Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a "sub string" method, but you can access specific points in strings with `[]`

Example:

`username = "#{first_name[0]}#{last_name}".downcase`

or you could monkey patch `String` like this:

```
class String
  def user_name
    first_name, last_name = self.split
    "#{first_name[0]}#{last_name}".downcase
  end
end
```

And then generate your string like this

```
name = Faker::Name.name
create_hash = {
  :Firstname => name.split.first,
  :Lastname  => name.split.last,
  :Username  => name.user_name,
}
Post.create!(create_hash)
```